# Аппроксимация функцией Гаусса в gnuplot

Tags: c++, математика, функции

Всем привет!

Стоит задача: я хочу оценить математическое ожидание и дисперсию моего распределения, которое у меня получилось после определенной задачи. На выходе у меня имеется файл из 2-х столбцов, в первом значения по X, во втором по Y.

Распределение выглядит следующим образом:
[image: распределение вероятностей]

Ясно, что это нормальное распределение, и мне его надо оценить, аппроксимировав функцией Гаусса. Что я и делаю через gnuplot:

```
pi=3.14; sig=0.1; mu=0.1;
Gauss(x) = 1./(sig*sqrt(2*pi)) * exp( -(x-mu)**2 / (2*sig**2) )
fit Gauss(x) "fit_aes_encryptText.txt" using 1:2 via sig, mu
```

Файл *fit_aes_encryptText.txt* выглядит следующим образом:

```
4 1
5 12
6 63
7 169
8 578
9 1591
10 3680
11 7506
12 13103
13 20269
14 27246
15 32781
16 34885
17 33215
18 27662
19 20135
20 13148
21 7665
22 3811
23 1650
24 570
25 201
26 48
27 11
28 5
```

Но gnuplot начинает ругаться:

```
iter      chisq       delta/lim  lambda   sig           mu           
0 6.2244369770e+09   0.00e+00  0.00e+00    1.000000e-01   1.000000e-01
     Singular matrix in Givens()
```

**Что я неправильно делаю?**

Comment: Почему Вы такое МЮ взяли? Оно же у Вас примерно 16. Плохие начальные условия.

Comment: И Сигма должна быть примерно 3. Нельзя брать начальные условия с потолка, их следует оценивать правильно.